Execute psql command in bash script with -c command
I'm trying to create a script to create a database, but I don't know how write the -c part:
psql -w -h ${HOST} -U ${USER} ${DATABASE} -c CREATE DATABASE ${DATABASE} WITH OWNER = ${USER} ENCODING = 'UTF8' CONNECTION LIMIT = -1 IS_TEMPLATE = False;

I tried:
psql -w -h ${HOST} -U ${USER} ${DATABASE} -c "CREATE DATABASE ${DATABASE} WITH OWNER = ${USER} ENCODING = 'UTF8' CONNECTION LIMIT = -1 IS_TEMPLATE = False;"

psql -w -h ${HOST} -U ${USER} ${DATABASE} -c ""CREATE DATABASE ${DATABASE} WITH OWNER = ${USER} ENCODING = 'UTF8' CONNECTION LIMIT = -1 IS_TEMPLATE = False;""

psql -w -h ${HOST} -U ${USER} ${DATABASE} -c {CREATE DATABASE ${DATABASE} WITH OWNER = ${USER} ENCODING = 'UTF8' CONNECTION LIMIT = -1 IS_TEMPLATE = False;}

psql -w -h ${HOST} -U ${USER} ${DATABASE} -c (CREATE DATABASE ${DATABASE} WITH OWNER = ${USER} ENCODING = 'UTF8' CONNECTION LIMIT = -1 IS_TEMPLATE = False;)

But no one works for me...

psql -w -h ${HOST} -U ${USER} ${DATABASE} -c "CREATE DATABASE ${DATABASE} WITH OWNER = ${USER} ENCODING = 'UTF8' CONNECTION LIMIT = -1 IS_TEMPLATE = False;"
what is "${DATABASE}" in this example, if it is not created yet?

The USER in your code is a standard environment variable, hopefully you're using it as-is and aren't overwriting it. In general don't use all-upper-case variable names for non-exported variables to avoid problems like that, see correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization. Also, do quote your variables, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, and copy/paste any script you write (or at least any you need help with) into http://shellcheck.net as the [tag:bash] tag instructs.

The mundane version with double quotes psql -w -h ${HOST} -U ${USER} ${DATABASE} -c "CREATE DATABASE ${DATABASE} WITH OWNER = ${USER} ENCODING = 'UTF8' CONNECTION LIMIT = -1 IS_TEMPLATE = False;" is nominally correct as far as Bash is concerned, but the documentation suggests that you should not have an equals sign or WITH around OWNER or after ENCODING or CONNECTION LIMIT. I'm not too familiar with PostgreSQL so there are probably additional errors in your SQL syntax.

(For what it's worth, your other attempts are nowhere near correct shell syntax.)

You didn't show the value of your variables. Aside from this, your first example (with the double quotes) looks most promising. no one works is a pretty meaningless error description. It would be very rare, that psql simply refuses to do anything, but would not produce at least an error message.

Assuming ${DATABASE} is pointing at the the same value, using it in both the psql connection string and CREATE DATABASE ${DATABASE} will fail. Either 1) ${DATABASE} does not exist and you won't be able to connect or 2) It does connect and it will fail because you cannot create a database that already exists.

The right way is to use psql variables:
psql -w -h ${HOST} -U ${USER} -d postgres -v db="$DATABASE" -v own="$USER" <<EOF
CREATE DATABASE :"db" WITH OWNER = :"own" ENCODING = 'UTF8' CONNECTION LIMIT = -1 IS_TEMPLATE = False;
EOF

This also avoids SQL injection problems.
You need to use a "here document", because psql doesn't substitute variables in commands passed with the option -c.
Also, not that you need to connect to a different database, normally postgres.
